# Progress Bar Keeps Repeating

Tags: javascript

How can the code below be modified such that when the progress bar is finished loading and it reaches the end, a seperate function (ie. test() )can be executed rather than just repeating and repeating like it is now.

```
<html> 
    <head> 
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
        var prg_width = 200; 

        function progress() { 
            var node = document.getElementById('progress'); 
            var w    = node.style.width.match(/\d+/); 

            if (w == prg_width) { 
                w = 0; 
            } 

            node.style.width = parseInt(w) + 5 + 'px'; 
        } 

        </script> 
    </head> 

    <body onload="var progress_run_id = setInterval(progress, 30);"> 

        <div style="border: 1px solid #808080; width:200px; height:5px;"> 
            <div id="progress" style="height:5px; width:0px; background-color:#DBDBDB;"/> 
        </div> 

    </body> 
</html>
```

Much thanks and appreciation for all your help.

Cheers,

Jay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html> 
<head>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var prg_width = 200; 
var progress_run_id = null;

function progress() { 
var node = document.getElementById('progress'); 
    var w  = node.style.width.match(/\d+/); 
    if (w == prg_width) { 
        clearInterval( progress_run_id );
        w = 0;
    } else {
        w = parseInt(w) + 5 + 'px';             
    }
    node.style.width = w;
}
function initialize(){
    progress_run_id = setInterval(progress, 30);
}
window.onload = initialize();
</script> 
</head> 
<body> 
        <div style="border: 1px solid #808080; width:200px; height:5px;"> 
        <div id="progress" style="height:5px; width:0px; background-color:#DBDBDB;"/> 
        </div> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: I prefer to keep HTML and Javascript separate so I used window.onload instead of <body onload>.

Comment: Worked like a charm. No errors. Lots of brilliant people in this world. Thank you so much!.

Answer (score 1):

Call this separate function instead of

`w = 0;`

line. Don't forget to `clearInterval(progress_run_id)` too.

Answer (score 0):

```
  var prg_width = 200; 

        function progress() { 
            var node = document.getElementById('progress'); 
            var w    = node.style.width.match(/\d+/); 

            if (w == prg_width) { 
                test(); // CHANGE THIS
                clearInterval(progress_run_id);
            } 

            node.style.width = parseInt(w) + 5 + 'px'; 
        }
```

That checks if the width is equal to the completed width. If it is, then clear the interval, and call your `test` function.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
        var prg_width = 200; 

        function progress() { 
            var node = document.getElementById('progress'); 
            var w    = node.style.width.match(/\d+/); 

            if (w == prg_width) { 
                test(); 
                clearInterval(progress_run_id);
            } 

            node.style.width = parseInt(w) + 5 + 'px'; 

        } 

        </script>
```

Comment: Thanks....this works fine and dandy, but then after its done and executes test() I get an error saying that progress_run_id is undefined? Any ideas?